# Why all child execute the main code?

Tags: c

I have this code with two childs and his father, but there is a problem because all childs (and father execute the code on main).

code:

```
int main() {
  switch (fork()) {
  case 0:     //child1
    break;
  default:
    switch (fork()) {
    case 0:   //child2
      break;
    default:  //father
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("hi\n");
}
```

outputs:

```
hi
hi
hi
```

Comment: Looks like correct behavior to me.

Comment: Because that's how it works!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect anything different... are you confused about how `fork` works? Are you confused about how `break` works? Are you confused about how _control flow_ works?

Comment: so, if i want to continue programming in main, how can i do it so it just appears once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fork()` it creates an almost-exact duplicate of the parent process, except for the return value from the `fork()` call. They both continue and execute all the same code, except for anything that depends on that return value.

Since the call to `printf()` is not conditional, it will be executed in both the father and child processes. If you want it to execute only in a specific process, you should put it in that branch of the `switch()` statement.